# OnlyOffice for Android building

Tags: onlyoffice

I was trying to build android app https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/documents-app-android and found that it needs X2Converter (which I was able to build with build tools https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/build_tools) and bunch of projects from core-ext (like ../../core-ext/native_base/android_base/libeditors and other) and document-android-editors folder (e.g. ../../document-android-editors/editors_docs/libgdocs). These modules are absent everywhere, are they open source?

I found another project which provides android binaries https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/editors-android-packages but it is unclear how to integrate it. It says I should add dependency url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/$userId/$repository") and implementation("com.onlyoffice.android:$artifactId:$version') but what should I put for userId, repository, artifactId and version?